# Run Error occurred in MPI_Recv, MPI_ERR_RANK invalid rank

Tags: c++, vector, mpi, matrix-multiplication

This is my first time working with MPI. I am wrking on a piece of code which does matrix multiplication using vectors and MPI. My program compiles successfully but when I run the program I keep getting errors.Can any one help me on why I am getting this errors. TIA

*** An error occurred in MPI_Recv**
  reported by process [139967236014081,139964394242049]
 **on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD**
  MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
  **MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
 ***    and potentially your MPI job)

```
/**********************************************************************                                                                                      
 * MPI-based matrix multiplication AxB=C                                                                                                                     
 *********************************************************************/

#include<ctime>     
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mpi.h"
#define N               10        /* number of rows and columns in matrix */

using namespace std;

MPI_Status status;

//double a[N][N],b[N][N],c[N][N];


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numtasks,taskid,numworkers,source,dest,rows,offset,i,j,k;
  int averow, extra;
  int loop = 1000;
  double randomNum;

  vector<vector<double> > a;
  vector<vector<double> > b;
  vector<vector<double> > c;
  vector<vector<double> > avg_Matrix;

  a.resize(N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a[i].resize(N);

  b.resize(N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    b[i].resize(N);

  c.resize(N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    c[i].resize(N);

  avg_Matrix.resize(N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    avg_Matrix[i].resize(N);

  srand ( time(NULL) ); //Initializing random seed.

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

  //cout<<"Number of works"<<numworkers;
  //cout<<"taskid"<<taskid;
  numworkers = numtasks-1;

  /*---------------------------- master ----------------------------*/
  if (taskid == 0) {
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
          randomNum = rand() % 400 + (-199.999); // generate randomnumbers between -199.999 to 199.999 for first matrix.
          a[i][j] = randomNum;

      }
    }

    cout<<"Printing First Matrix"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i< N; i++)
    {
       cout<<endl;
       for(j=0; j< N; j++)
       {
           cout<<a[i][j];
           cout<<"\t";
       }
    }

    /* second matrix. */
    for(i=0; i< N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j< N; j++)
        {
            randomNum = rand() % 400 + (-199.999); // generate randomnumbers between -199.999 to 199.999 for first matrix.
            b[i][j] = randomNum;
        }
     }

     cout<<endl;
     cout<<endl;
     /* Printing the second Matrix*/
     cout<<"Printing Second Matrix"<<endl;
     for(i=0; i< N; i++)
     {
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=0; j< N; j++)
        {
            cout<<b[i][j];
            cout<<"\t";
        }
     }

    /* send matrix data to the worker tasks */
    averow = N/numworkers;
    extra = N%numworkers;
    offset = 0;

    for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++)
    {
      rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow;
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE,dest,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      offset = offset + rows;
    }

    /* wait for results from all worker tasks */
    if(taskid == 0) {
    for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
    {
      source = i;
      MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
   }

    cout<<"Here is the result matrix:"<<endl;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        cout<<"\t"<<c[i][j];
      cout<<endl;
    }
  }

  /*---------------------------- worker----------------------------*/
  if (taskid > 0) {
    source = 0;
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&a, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&b, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* Matrix multiplication */
    for (k=0; k<N; k++){
      for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
          c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
      }
     }
    }

    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&c, rows*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must allocate your 2D arrays in contiguous memory if you want to send/recv more than one row at a time. As a side note, you should consider using MPI collective operations such as `MPI_Bcast()`, `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Gatherv()`. In a typical MPI app, rank `0` would do some work before waiting for the other ranks.

Comment: You are trying to send objects of type `std::vector`. MPI does not support this data type (however, it can be done with help of Boost.MPI wrapper).